# Communicate to Android Device over USB

Tags: linux-kernel, usb, embedded-linux

I am developing an application on Am3352 based board which needs to communicate to an android device (tablet/phone) over USB. I need to exchange some custom data bytes (which will be understood only by my application and an application running in the android device) over USB.

When I connect the android tablet to my AM3352 board, I am getting prints on the console with VID PID etc which indicates that the device is getting detected. What I need to know is, how to make the kernel assign a dev file for the device. For example, when we connect a usb to serial converter we will get /dev/ttyUSBx file so that we can open it and write/read to this file. Similarly is it possible for direct usb connection?

I was expecting a /dev/ttyACMx device file to be generated so that I can write and read to it. The CDC/Modem support is enabled in kernel. (I am not sure if this will help but just tried it anyway).

Kindly let me know how I can get a device file name associated with the device so that I can read and write to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you have to know what USB kind of your android device is. How this device is recognized on your linux box? As a mass-storage or CDC or anything else? Then you can try to communicate with it. And you don't have to create any device in /dev/ to communicate with android via USB. Take a look at libusb library.

In your example - /dev/ttyUSBx is created because kernel knows that this is communication device class. So you also need to know what kind of USB device is this android device.

Comment: My understanding is that an android device can function in different modes, right? When the usb is connected a pop-up is displayed in the tablet asking which mode it wants to work in. When I select Camera (PTP) I am able to detect the device as LIB_CLASS_PTP (0x06) and when I select Buit-In CDROM option it is getting detected as LIB_CLASS_MASS_STORAGE(0x08).

Comment: I need to know if there is any mechanism to make it work as Communication Class Device (0x02) or Data Class Device(0x0A). If so, I think it, when the device is connected a /dev/ttyUSBx or /dev/ttyACMx file will be generated automatically which can be used in fopen, read and write functions for communication. Is this possible ?

Comment: If I understood you properly - you want to communicate via your own protocol over USB. First - you need to make the tablet to function as a communication device and it can be done in Android in the kernel. To do it you would take a look at gadget drivers for Android kernel if there is any (probably G_SERIAL) which can be used as such kind of device. Then you need to write program for Android for servicing such device.

Comment: Thanks. I am looking at a workaround now. The android device will work as the the host and my device as the slave. I am looking at available usb slave sample codes. Kindly let me know if you are aware of any.

Comment: Oops seems like I misunderstood you. I thought that Android will be usb-device, but you want it to function as a usb-host. Well, your device should present itself as a usb communication device. If you run Linux on it you can use g_serial gadget driver on it. It such a case after you plug in it to android you can use libusb on android or just /dev/ttyUSBx for communication with your usb-device. You have also another possibility - you can write your own driver (usb classless or proprietary) for your usb-device and all the communication protocol is up to you. Good luck.

Comment: Hi, do you have any samples or link to some site that explains how to use the g_serial gagdet driver properly. Changes to be done in kernel side and some sample application would be great help..

Comment: First - your device need to have usb device controller and proper driver for it and this driver should register itself in linux usb gadget stack. Then you can run g_serial. Documentation for g_serial is in kernel sources: Documentation/usb/gadget_serial.txt

Comment: Thanks...I did the necessary steps and I am getting /dev/ttyGS0 file upon running modprobe g_serial.. I have two usb ports and I have both of them configured as peripherals.. But I am getting only GS0 file. Any reason ttyGS1 is not generated? Or do I have to do anything extra for this?

Comment: I didn't test it but I think you can do something like this: modprobe g_serial n_ports=2